# Qt 5.12 for iOS: build system

Tags: ios, xcode, qt

Accordingly to https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-94562 and https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtbase/+/353189 I expect `Qt (qmake)` version 5.12.11 will produce 'Xcode 12.0-compatible' or 'modern' `xCode` project. Unfortunately, I see project format is still '`xCode` `3.2-compatible`'. Where am I wrong? Is some additional setup required?

`xCode` `13` drops support of Legacy build system, so I am in a big trouble.

Answer (score 2):

So I encountered this problem in `Qt 5.15.5`, building with `Xcode 13`, just as you predicted. I found this https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtbase/+/353118. The `Xcode 13` told me that it wasn't going to put up with the old build system any more - the one that was used prior to `Xcode 10`, I think. The reason it was defaulting to that old system was exactly what you were observing - `qmake` always makes projects that use the legacy build system. The `qmake` `mkspec` called `macx-xcode` (stored at /qtbase/mkspecs/macx-xcode which is a folder containing some .mk files and related other files) controls how `qmake` generates an Xcode project. It does so partly by containing some templates for projects and workspaces that it will use to dynamically flesh out a full project. One of those is called `WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings` (within the `macx-xcode` folder). It's just a place-holder to be filled with workspace-level settings that apply to all projects sharing it. It's written in the same `XML` that comprises all `Xcode` project files. It has almost nothing in it EXCEPT two lines that are screwing things up for both of us (the ones that the patch for the bug I linked removes). In your version of `Qt` right up until `5.15.5`, it looks like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"  "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>BuildSystemType</key>
    <string>Original</string>
    <key>IDEWorkspaceSharedSettings_AutocreateContextsIfNeeded</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The fix is to remove the first key-value pair, because it's saying specifically use the "Original" build system which predates `Xcode 10`. Just remove the two lines after `<dict>` and things should be better. For me it fixed things right up. In `Qt 5.15.6`, this change has been incorporated, so it's one of the bugs that fixed for that dot-release, but it should cause no harm to fix up your local version. If you don't build `Qt` from source (which I do, along with a handful of other mods), you could look at going to `5.15.6` directly. In my case, I just made the change in addition others I've made and I check it into my mirror repository. But again, it will cause no harm to doctor your local copy of Qt with this fix. It just get's tricky as a maintenance issue if you're coordinating with a big team.